# Serving Static Content -- Wordpress Cookieless Subdomain

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, subdomain

I've followed [this guide](https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/wordpress/wordpress-how-to-serve-static-content-from-a-cookieless-domain/) to the brim, but on step 3 I'm being stumped.

I've declared the following in the wp-config.php (customized to my domain):

```
define("WP_CONTENT_URL", "http://static.domainname.com");
define("COOKIE_DOMAIN", "www.domainname.com");
define("WP_PLUGIN_URL", "http://static.domainname.com/plugins");
```

And I've gone in phpMyAdmin in cPanel and done this update:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,
 'http://www.domainname.com/wp-content/uploads/','http://static.domainname.com/uploads/')
```

However, I get this result:

[image: 0 rows affected phpMyAdmin]

When I update new content, the images get prepended "static," which is good, but my stylesheets also have "static," and since there's no content loaded on that subdomain, my site gets wrecked. And all existing images need to be uploaded to the subdomain so they are also served via "static."

Am I following the guide above wrongly?

Comment: Well, you say there's no content on the subdomain. You may want to duplicate all content from the uploads folder to the static subdomain, as that would allow your website to actually get the content (because right now it doesn't exist). But if you're doing this for optimisation, then there's 10 other, simpler, steps you can do before trying the more complicated solutions.

Comment: Hi Friso! Do you mean copy and paste the uploads on the subdomain and then update via phpMyAdmin? I've been ravenous for optimization, and this one is one of the last ones in the big lists. Serving static content is giving me an F on all tests, while I sit at As and Bs elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. The files need to exist on the static domain before you can show them of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you've stumbled upon this, I forgot to keep

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts`
```

above the update posts.

In final, the phpMyAdmin would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts`;
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,
 'http://www.domainname.com/wp-content/uploads/','http://static.domainname.com/')
```